# Arrange three images (with an own caption for each) in two rows using subfig package

Tags: graphics, captions, subfloats

I would like to arrange three figures like this:
a long one on the left and two smaller square ones right to it (above each other). All three images need to have a separate caption.

I am using the document class 'book' and for the figures the 'subfig' package and would like to stay with this. I have already tried to arrange it with a minipage whereas (as far as I understood) one can arrange it the way I want to but only with a caption for the left and a common caption for both others.

Right now I use the following script where all images are arranged beside each other:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} 
\usepackage{overpic} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{float} 


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat[ \label{fig:HdRM}]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{HdRM.eps}}
\subfloat[ \label{fig:vRBd}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{vRBd.eps}}
\subfloat[ \label{fig:msD}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{msd.eps}}
\linespread{1.2}
\captionsetup{font=small} 
\caption[Impact of ...]{Figure a) shows...  b) ... depicts. c) illustrates....}
\label{fig:Impact}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I spent already so much time with searching for a solution but I could not find anything that fits into my document. 
I would be so happy if someone could help me!

Comment: Note that `\begin{figure}[h]` is quite dangerous; use `[htp]` in order to help LaTeX in finding the best place for the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest idea is to use a couple of `tabular` environments. Not knowing the relative heights it's difficult to say more.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat[ \label{fig:HdRM}]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{HdRM.eps}}
\end{tabular}\qquad % some space
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\subfloat[ \label{fig:vRBd}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{vRBd.eps}}
\\
\subfloat[ \label{fig:msD}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{msd.eps}}
\end{tabular}
\caption[Impact of ...]{Figure a) shows...  b) ... depicts. c) illustrates....}
\label{fig:Impact}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the bottom subcaptions to be vertically aligned, use `\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}` in both tabulars.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem with minipages. This example solve the question?

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.65\linewidth}
\subfloat[ \label{fig:HdRM}]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.30\linewidth}
\subfloat[ \label{fig:vRBd}]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}}\\
\subfloat[ \label{fig:msD}]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-1x1}}
\end{minipage}

\caption[Impact of ...]{Figure a) shows...  b) ... depicts. c) illustrates....}
\label{fig:Impact}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: *Beware of the Jabberwocky, my son.* In this case the Jabberwocky is `\begin{figure}[h]`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Ooopps, deleted in 3, 2 ....